# Historic flight times?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, flight-status

I need to find the departure and arrival times for a flight that was delayed last December, is there any way I can do this without having to pay a subscription?

The flight was from Edinburgh to Paris CDG

Comment: Did you turn on the phone at landing? Check message/SMS app. Google is tracing you, check Google timeline. You want more precise data? You should write it down, or ask us exactly which flight (and date).

Comment: BTW: this is not a duplicate of that question. The "non duplicate question" were explicitly about US airline, so the answers provide just FAA data (so it miss the European FR24). This question ask for non subscription way, which is not on the other question, nor in the answers. -- For sure there will be a dudplicate question, but we should help our users (and google) to find the right one, not just looking the titles)

Comment: That question explicitly asked for *international flights*, so it is duplicate. It could do with more answers, yes.